# PHP Mail Function Slowing Down Page

Tags: performance, php

I Have 2 Pages PageA for posting enquiry and PageB - Thank you page.

I have added SendMail PHP Function to PageA Which Sends Mail to 3 People Along with attachments once enquiry is posted in PageA.

Now after this is done I am Redirecting to PageB which is Thank you page.

Now the Problem is it is taking so long(more than 2 seconds) for redirection to PageB to happen since the mail function in PageA is slowing down this.

Please let me know how to get rid of this

Answer (score 0):

How about you send the emails using a separate script triggered by the cron job?

Answer (score 0):

Some options include:

1) Queue the mail in a local mail server and let it handle the details of reaching the final destination. This option may require you to set up a mail server, but delivery should be instant and allow the script to proceed.

2) Don't deliver the mail immediately, but rather flag in a database that it is pending and have a cron job running to send pending email separately from the web page.